# Read in a certain line only?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program to read in a configuration file and I only want to read certain lines. Example:

config.txt:

```
This is a test configuration text file
It isn't supposed to read this line or the line above it

Read this line, but not the white space above or below it

Don't read this line or the white space above or below it

Read this line, but not the white space above or below it
```

I'm using your basic I/O:

```
FILE *File;
File = fopen("config.txt", "r");
```

Comment: Either count lines, or put section identifiers into your text file.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: Read all the lines, and decide which to process and which to ignore.

Comment: Hi John! Welcome to stack overflow. In order for us to help you, we need to fully understand the problem. With your current question, it is unclear what you are asking because you gave us a minimal example of `config.txt` without any explanation of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What does "certain lines" even mean? How do you determine if a line should be read without knowing what it is?

Comment: @UnholySheep Like, how about this example? `char *name = readLine(4) // reads line 4 of the text file` another example: `char *address = readLine(7) // reads line 7 of the text file`?

Comment: @JohnF Create a function that scans for the next newline character, and call that n-1 times before reading the next line.

Comment: You should at least tell us how the "certain lines" are specified. Is the program supposed to just guess which lines you need?

Comment: @JohnF You need to make that part of the question. Also you should try to code it up yourself and ask a question if you can't get your code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark lines you don't want to read with some character or a number, so whenever input stream reads it, you can skip it.

0 This is a test configuration text file
0 It isn't supposed to read this line or the line above it

1 Read this line, but not the white space above or below it

0 Don't read this line or the white space above or below it

0 Read this line, but not the white space above or below it

Then check value in first place of every line and skip it/ read it.
Or use something like multiline comments in C /* commented out */ check for opening character and skip everything before closing character.